# Dynamic select query according to form fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form with two fields. The user can fill in either one or both and the MySQL database should be queried accordingly.

Here is my php code:

```
$number1 = $_POST['number1'];
$number2= $_POST['number2'];

$set = FALSE;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

   if (!empty($number1 ))
   {
      $query .= " WHERE number1 = ".$number1."";
      $set = TRUE;  
   }
   if (!empty($number2))
   {
      $query .= ($set===TRUE ? " AND" : " WHERE") . " number2 = ".$number2."";
   }


$data = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
```

The code works fine if either number1 or both of the fields are filled in. However when only the second field is filled in I get the error:

> Couldn't execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

If I echo the query it is shown correctly:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE number2 = *entered value*

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: You should be sanitizing your input, and please don't use mysql_query it is deprecated. Your code leaves your whole site open to injection. Look at php.net/pdo and php.net/mysqli as alternatives.

Comment: In addition to @DavidHoude comment, this is cool learning tools on using PDO method, which I benefited so much for my work.  http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/2012/10/16/pdo-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I use validation on my form so the user can only input digits. You are absolutely right about mysqli. I am using it now but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

have you forget escape values? u can use somthing like this

```
$fields = array();
if(!empty($_POST['number1'])) {
    $fields[] = 'number1='.mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['number1']);
}
if(!empty($_POST['number2'])) {
    $fields[] = 'number2='.mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['number2']);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implide(" AND ", $fields);
$data = mysqli_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
```

mysql extension is deprecated, use mysqli instead

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with escape strings. It didn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$number1 = $_POST['number1'];
$number2= $_POST['number2'];

$set = FALSE;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

   if (!empty($number1 ))
   {
      $query .= " WHERE number1 = ".$number1."";
      $set = TRUE;  
   }
   if (!empty($number2))
   {
      if($set==FALSE)
          $query .= " WHERE number2 = ".$number2;
      else
        $query .= " AND number2 = ".$number2;
   }
```

Comment: I have tested your code. It doesn't make a difference. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the error because of the assignment. You wrote $set===TRUE, its == not ===
The error is here:

```
 if (!empty($number2))
 {
  $query .= ($set===TRUE ? " AND" : " WHERE") . " number2 = ".$number2."";
 }
```